# powershell array clear method and assignment

Tags: arrays, powershell, variable-assignment

The assignment operator = “Sets the value of a variable to the specified value” as said in the [reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-5.1) . Not surprisingly, changes on a variable (in my case an array) that has been previously assigned to another variable do not affect the value of this latter one.

```
    PS C:\> $V="a", "b", "c"
    PS C:\> $A=$V
    PS C:\> write-host "A before new value of V: $A"
    A before new value of V: a b c
    PS C:\> $V="e","f"
    PS C:\> write-host "A after new value of V: $A"
    A after new value of V: a b c
    PS C:\>
```

But when the method clear() is used the behaviour seems different.

```
PS C:\> $V="a", "b", "c"
PS C:\> $A=$V
PS C:\> write-host "A before clearing V: $A"
A before clearing V: a b c
PS C:\> $V.clear()
PS C:\> write-host "A after clearing V: $A"
A after clearing V: 
PS C:\>
```

It seems that clear() method applied on $V acts also on $A. As if the assignment were by reference, strange enough, only for this method. In fact, if a new value is assigned to $V after having cleared it, $A is still affected only by the clear.

```
PS C:\> $V="a", "b", "c"
PS C:\> $A=$V
PS C:\> write-host "A before clearing V: $A"
A before clearing V: a b c
PS C:\> $V.clear()
PS C:\> $V="e","f"
PS C:\> write-host "A after clearing V: $A"
A after clearing V:   
PS C:\>
```

There are possibilities to avoid this effect, although not precisely identical: $A=$V.clone() or use of cmdlet Clear-Variable -name V or $V=$null instead $V.clear() or perhaps others better than these that somebody could suggest.

But my question is:
how to explain the "propagation" of the effect of clear method on $V to the other array $A?

Tests have been done on PS ver.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Clone()` method to get *true* copy of an array.

```
$V = "a", "b", "c"
$A = $V.Clone()
Write-Host "A before new value of V: $A"
$V = "e","f"
Write-Host "A after  new value of V: $A"
```

> ```
> A before new value of V: a b c
> A after  new value of V: a b c
> ```

For explanation, read [Copying Arrays and Hash Tables](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/ebookv2/posts/chapter-4-arrays-and-hashtables#copying-arrays-and-hash-tables):

> Copying arrays or hash tables from one variable to another works, *but
>   may produce unexpected results*. The reason is that arrays and hash
>   tables are not stored directly in variables, which always store only a
>   single value. When you work with arrays and hash tables, you are
>   dealing with a **reference** to the array or hash table. So, if you
>   copy the contents of a variable to another, only the reference will be
>   copied, not the array or the hash table. That could result in the
>   following unexpected behavior:
>
> ```
> $array1 = 1,2,3
> $array2 = $array1
> $array2[0] = 99
> $array1[0]
> 99
> ```
>
> Although the contents of `$array2` were changed in this example, this
>   affects `$array1` as well, because they are both *identical*. The
>   variables `$array1` and `$array2` internally *reference the same
>   storage area*. Therefore, you have to create a copy if you want to
>   copy arrays or hash tables,:
>
> ```
> $array1 = 1,2,3
> $array2 = $array1.Clone()
> $array2[0] = 99
> $array1[0]
> 1
> ```
>
> Whenever you add new elements to an array (or a hash table) or remove
>   existing ones, a copy action takes place automatically in the
>   background and its results are stored in a new array or hash table.
>   The following example clearly shows the consequences:
>
> ```
> # Create array and store pointer to array in $array2:
> $array1 = 1,2,3
> $array2 = $array1
>
> # Assign a new element to $array2. A new array is created in the process and stored in $array2:
> $array2 += 4
> $array2[0]=99
>
> # $array1 continues to point to the old array:
> $array1[0]
> 1
> ```

BTW, you can meet the terms *Value type*, *Reference type* and *Pointer type* more often…

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I get that the assignment operation between arrays is by reference to a common table. In some cases a clone is done automatically, but not always. This can explain the different behaviours I noted. To avoid unexpected results it is safer to assign clone instead the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

For me what you see is normal, I try to explain myself :

```
$V="a", "b", "c"
$a = $V
```

now `$a` contains the same reference as `$V`. if you clear `$V` then `$a` is cleared.

now if you write `$V = "b","c"`, you affect `$V` with the reference of a new tab. and this reference is not the same that you affect to `$a`. so now if you clear `$V`, `$a` is not cleared.

Am I clear enought ?

Comment: Then the assignment between arrays is by reference towards a common table.